# Select nodes on page by text fragment

Tags: javascript, dom, replace, find, nodes

Select all nodes on the page, the text inside of which contains a specific phrase.
For example, in the DOM structure has the following nodes:

```
<div class="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<option class="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</option>
<div class="three">Example: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<label class="four">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</label>
```

I need to choose the nodes that will meet phrase 'Example:'.
Such nodes may has any classes or has no one ...
You tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that returns elements where the nodes text matches a regular expression:

```js
function getNodeByTextContent(regEx) {
  var all = document.querySelectorAll('*');
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(all).filter(function (el) { 
    return el.textContent.match(regEx);
  });
}

//EG: all nodes where the text begins with 'example'
var matchedNodes = getNodeByTextContent(/^example/i);
for (i = 0; i < matchedNodes.length; ++i) {
  matchedNodes[i].style.color = "green";
}
```

```html
<div class="one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<option class="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</option>
<div class="three">Example: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
<label class="four">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options I can think of

First is to grab all the nodes and then just loop though running a test.

The other would be to use XPath to retrieve the nodes

```
//*[contains(., "Example")]
```

would select all elements that contain the string "Example" somewhere in there

Note that this would include parent elements (as they also include the string) If you wanted purely leaf elements:

```
//*[contains(., "Example") and not(child::*)]
```

would do it, but would not retrieve an element such as

```
<p>Example: this is an <em>important</em> example</p>
```